# How to transform rows to columns using Postgres SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab, postgresql-9.4

**I have the data in the following structure**
[image: Question]

***Desired Output***

[image: https://imgur.com/a/855njBn][1]]

Comment: Why the MySQL tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres (starting in 9.4) supports the `filter` syntax for conditional aggregation.  So I would recommend:

```
SELECT customer_id,
       MAX(value) FILTER (WHERE name = 'age') as age,
       MAX(value) FILTER (WHERE name = 'marketing_consent') as marketing_consent,
       MAX(value) FILTER (WHERE name = 'gender') as gender
FROM t
GROUP BY customer_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT customer_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN name='age' THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS age,
    MAX(CASE WHEN name='marketing_consent' THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS marketing_consent,
    MAX(CASE WHEN name='gender' THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS gender
FROM table
GROUP BY customer_id;
```

You just group by customer_id and pick out each value in its own column.  You need an aggregate function on the various values columns for syntactical reasons, which is why each column has a Max function.

Not e that it would of course be better to store the data in a normalized fashion.  Also, with newer versions of postgres, you can use filter instead of case, which I find a bit more readable.